# Fast access to bmesh verts/edges/faces from python?

Tags: python, bmesh

I'm trying to build a large [BMesh](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bmesh.types.html) from scratch in python. I know you can add vertices (or faces or edges) to a BMesh one at a time:

```py
  for v in verts:
    face = bme.verts.new(v)
```

but this is *really* slow for many vertices/edges/faces. Is there a batch way to add many vertices at once, avoiding the python overhead?

Googling around I found that the old mesh supported `foreach_set()` and `foreach_get()` which were supposed to be fast, but I gather those don't work anymore?

Comment: The foreach methods are available to the `Mesh` not a `bmesh` and still work. Also  `Mesh.from_pydata(...)` is pretty quick.

Answer (score 0):

One way to speed this up would be to use a Python list comprehension. It's probably not the exact answer you're looking for, but it may help with optimizing the code.